# testing if a link is a youtube link.

Tags: jquery, asp.net, youtube

I am trying to write a function that will test if a string belongs to a certain movie streaming site then performs some function accordingly. For my own purposes I am trying to get it to split the "ID" part of the url and embed it.

For example it would test the string if "youtube" was contained by the string.

```
   function testingURL() {
      var url = $("#<%=txtYoutubeLink.ClientID %>").val();           
         if(url.toLowerCase().indexOf("youtube") > 0)  // this is where my function fails. 
        {
          var Youtubeurl = url.toString().split('v=')[1];
            getTitle(Youtubeurl);
              document.getElementById('video').src = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + Youtubeurl
                }
    else{
        var Vimeourl = url.toString().split('//vimeo.com/')[1];
        document.getElementById('video').src = "//player.vimeo.com/video/" + Vimeourl;
    }

    $("#<%=txtYoutubeLink.ClientID %>").val() = null;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question!

Comment: And you forgot to indent your code properly! (I wonder which's the worse part)

Comment: I've read this question 10 times trying to find a question, but I can't, and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: so many things about this are strange for some reason my question is missing a paragraph. Also my nickname is "Sebi"! o_o

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Though it would be better to add a clear question to the question, I just noticed the comment in this line of the provided code:

```
if(url.toLowerCase().indexOf("youtube") > 0)  // this is where my function fails.
```

You should check what `var url = $("#<%=txtYoutubeLink.ClientID %>").val();` actually returns, because in case the url starts with youtube, the result of

```
url.toLowerCase().indexOf("youtube")
```

is `0`.
`indexOf()` does not check if a substring is contained in another string, but returns the position (starting at 0), in case the substring is contained, or `-1` in case the substring is not contained. Just adjust to

```
if(url.toLowerCase().indexOf("youtube") >= 0)
```

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf